# A word/word phrase meaning 'a tiny detail'/'a small thing"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am looking for a word/word phrase native English speakers use as an expression for 'a tiny detail' / 'a small thing' (when mentioning something but adding that it is not so important). I came across the word 'a trifle' but am not familiar if and when it is used in this meaning. Do you say - 'such a trifle'?

Example: Such a tiny detail/such a small thing - I wish there was a night lamp in the room.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean "minutia (plural - "minutiae"? Without more context, I don't feel confident giving this as an answer. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/minutia?s=t

Comment: @Nancy There is an example; it's certainly not *jot/tittle* territory.

Comment: *Trifle* sounds far more natural to me than the words given in any of the answers. If your question is *Do you say "such a trifle"?* then the answer is yes. Otherwise, if you want a different word, you need to explain what's wrong with *trifle* itself, such that something else would be better. (And just saying you aren't familiar with it can be resolved by any dictionary.)

Comment: Thank you for all your comments! I just wanted to find out whether 'a trifle' is used in everyday speech, not just an entry in the dictionary :-). I do not find anything wrong with the word. Thank you once again!

Comment: @Jason Bassford So it would be fine to say: such a trifle - I wish there was a night lamp in the room?

Comment: Perhaps not those *exact* words, but essentially yes. *I hate to bother you with a trifle, but I wish there were a night light in my room.* Or *This is such a trifle, but could I have a night light in my room?*

Comment: Thank you Jason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[no biggie](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/no-biggie) (Cambridge Dictionary)

> used to say that something is not a serious problem:
>
> I was a little disappointed that they don't serve brunch on Saturdays,
>   but hey, no biggie.

Using **no biggie** in the example sentence (*It's* being optional):

> (It's) no biggie, but I wish there was a night lamp in the room.

Merriam-Webster lists [no biggie](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/(it's)%20no%20biggie) as an idiom (informal, with or without *it's*).

Another simple definition and example of the phrase [no biggie](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/no_biggie) (Lexico.com):

> Used to indicate that something is of little consequence.
>
> ‘no biggie, I'm not in a hurry’

You could also say "no big deal." Lexico.com gives the same defintion for it.

---

(US, SE Region)

Comment: Thank you! A great suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

**minutia** noun

> mi·​nu·​tia | \ mə-ˈnü-sh(ē-)ə  , mī-, -ˈnyü-\
>   plural minutiae\ mə-​ˈnü-​shē-​ˌē  , -​ˌī , mī-​ , -​ˈnyü-​ , -​sh(ē-​)ə \
>
> Definition of minutia
>
> : a minute or minor detail —usually used in plural
>
> He was bewildered by the contract's minutiae.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minutia

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

It’s a **nitpick**:

> a carping, petty criticism.

([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nitpicking) based off Random House)

For example:

> Kind of a nitpick but am I the only one who hates how Black Widow's hair looks so fresh out the salon for a spy. Lol

([ifunny.co](https://ifunny.co/picture/kind-of-a-nitpick-but-am-i-the-only-one-SolWZ6Ts3))

Comment: Its a *nit*, perhaps.  The nitpick is the person who harps on it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

**picayunish**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/picayune)

> of little value or account; small; trifling.
>
> petty, carping, or prejudiced.

As in"

*So picayunish, but I wish there was a night lamp in the room.*

Hear the word "picky" in picayune (though they're not related)? That's one way to remember it.  Sometimes, picayune details that leads them to understanding. Often they are so small and inconsequential that they just ... fade away!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!